# check point on every syscall

Tags: linux, ptrace, checkpoint

I am trying to use CRIU (https://github.com/checkpoint-restore/criu) to dump/restore the snapshot of an execution for every system call.
I am trying to dump through the following way (the binary sample simply outputs "hello\n" 5 times to the console.

```
int dump(int cnt)
{
    char num [PATH_MAX];
    itoa(cnt, num);

    char filename [PATH_MAX];
    sprintf(filename, "dirs/dir%s", num); 
    //printf("%s\n", filename);
    
    int fd = open(filename, O_DIRECTORY);
    if(fd == -1) {
        fprintf(stderr, "failed to open: %s\n", strerror(errno));
        exit(1);
    }

    int ret;
    ret = criu_init_opts();
    criu_set_service_binary("./sample");
    criu_set_images_dir_fd(fd);
    criu_set_log_level(4);
    criu_set_log_file("dump.log");

    ret = criu_dump();
    close(fd);

    return ret;
}
```

But the function criu_dump sends me the error message

```
Can't exec criu swrk: No such file or directory
Can't read request: Connection reset by peer
Can't receive response: Connection reset by peer
```

and I don't have much of an idea how to resolve these.

I have created main function according to https://github.com/skeeto/ptrace-examples/blob/master/minimal_strace.c, and I have written below as well.

```
int
main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc <= 1)
        FATAL("too few arguments: %d", argc);

    pid_t pid = fork();
    switch (pid) {
        case -1: /* error */
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        case 0:  /* child */
            ptrace(PTRACE_TRACEME, 0, 0, 0);
            /* Because we're now a tracee, execvp will block until the parent
             * attaches and allows us to continue. */
            execvp(argv[1], argv + 1);
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
    }

    /* parent */
    waitpid(pid, 0, 0); // sync with execvp
    ptrace(PTRACE_SETOPTIONS, pid, 0, PTRACE_O_EXITKILL);

    int cnt = 1;
    for (;;) {
        /* Enter next system call */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        if (waitpid(pid, 0, 0) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));

        /* Gather system call arguments */
        struct user_regs_struct regs;
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        long syscall = regs.orig_rax;

        /* Print a representation of the system call */
        int ret = dump(cnt++);
        printf("at cnt: %d, dump ret: %d, error: %s\n", cnt - 1, ret, strerror(ret));

        fprintf(stderr, "%ld(%ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld, %ld)",
                syscall,
                (long)regs.rdi, (long)regs.rsi, (long)regs.rdx,
                (long)regs.r10, (long)regs.r8,  (long)regs.r9);

        /* Run system call and stop on exit */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_SYSCALL, pid, 0, 0) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        if (waitpid(pid, 0, 0) == -1)
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));

        /* Get system call result */
        if (ptrace(PTRACE_GETREGS, pid, 0, &regs) == -1) {
            fputs(" = ?\n", stderr);
            if (errno == ESRCH)
                exit(regs.rdi); // system call was _exit(2) or similar
            FATAL("%s", strerror(errno));
        }

        /* Print system call result */
        fprintf(stderr, " = %ld\n", (long)regs.rax);
    }
}
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?

I wrote `./minimum_strace ./sample` to run the program. I ran on Ubuntu 16.04 x86 architecture.

Comment: Don't use `itoa()`, use `snprintf(filename, sizeof(filename), "dirs/dir%i", cnt)` instead. Does directory exist before open?

Comment: The directory is made beforehand

Comment: `criu_set_service_binary()` allows to override criu service binary instead of default `criu`. `./sample` is not a criu service binary. You don't need to call this function.

Comment: `Can't exec criu swrk: No such file or directory
Can't read request: Connection reset by peer
Can't receive response: Connection reset by peer`
are the error messages that is given to me now for every dumping.

Comment: Do you have `criu` executable in your `PATH`?